# How to select cells in the worksheet to create a Pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a pivot table. Eventually I will use Power Automate to make it run every day.

I used Record Macro in Excel to figure out how to create a Pivot table.

```vb
Range("A1:W37").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R37C23", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Sheet19!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=8
Sheets("Sheet19").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
```

How do I select all cells in the worksheet and store them in a variable?

Then I can put that variable after SourceData:= _ (this will replace the code "Sheet1!R1C1:R37C23").

I found on the Internet that I can select all cells with data:

```vb
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsPT As Worksheet, rngData As Range, wb As Workbook
    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook   'or some other specific workbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1) 'or some other specific sheet
    
    'same as selecting A1 and pressing Ctrl+A
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Set wsPT = wb.Worksheets.Add() 'get a reference to the new sheet
    
    'create pivot cache
    Set pc = wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                           SourceData:=rngData, Version:=8)
    'create pivot table
    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=wsPT.Range("A3"), _
                      TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=8)
    
    'work with `pt`....
End Sub
```

You get more control if you split up the creation of the pivot cache and the pivot table into separate steps.

Comment: Hello sir, I find there is a problem with the code by accidently add a new sheet. If the excel only contain sheet1, everything works smoothly and the sheet2 will contain the correct PivotTable. However, if there is a sheet2 already it will have Run-time error 1004 (This command requires at least two rows of source data). After click debug, I find the problem is with set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable this line and more specific one is related to wsPT.Range("A3"). Do you have any suggestion to improve the code?

Comment: Other sheets in the workbook shouldn't be a problem as long as you correctly specify the location of `rngData`.  Are you saying your data might not always be on the first sheet?  If that's the case you'll need to adjust your code.

Comment: After I change Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1) to Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") it won't pop any error message, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find a whole bunch of Excel-VBA-Pivot resources from this URL.

https://www.contextures.com/

Also, consider recording a Macro as you click through the steps that you need to do, and learn from the code the the Macro Recorder generates. I guarantee that you'll learn a ton from these types of exercises.